# Slug is not shown for my custom post type

Tags: plugin-development

Registering a custom post type as following and the slug input is not shown. Any ideas why?

```
res = register_post_type( 'twig_anything_tmplt', [
        'label' => 'Twig Templates',
        'labels' => [
            'name' => 'Twig Templates',
            'singular_name' => 'Twig Template',
            'menu_name' => 'Twig Templates',
            'add_new_item' => 'Add New Twig Template',
            'edit_item' => 'Edit Twig Template',
            'new_item' => 'New Twig Template',
            'view_item' => 'View Twig Template',
            'search_items' => 'Search Twig Templates',
            'not_found' => 'No Twig templates found',
            'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Twig templates found in trash',
        ],
        'description' => 'Twig templates used by the Twig Anything plugin.',
        'exclude_from_search' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => false,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
        'menu_position' => 20,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-images-alt2',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'supports' => ['title', 'editor'],
        'has_archive' => false,
        'rewrite' => [
            'slug' => 'twig_anything_tmplt',
            'with_front' => true,
            'feeds' => false,
            'pages' => false,
        ]
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its there you just need to click on "screen options" and make sure the checkbox is checked

[image]

Comment: I don't want the slug to be displayed in a separate secton. I need it directly under the post title, just as it is displayed for posts/pages.